# (Internal) Render Won't Save as Transparent Image

Tags: animation, blender-internal-render-engine

So I have quite a simple question, but basically I have a picture of a model and want to save it as transparent. So I went up to the Render Layers panel, Layers, and deselected "sky" and rendered it out. It showed that checkered grey background with the object still there, so things were going good! I saved it, but for some reason there is a black background and it isn't a transparent image. Any help? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Please add more information to your question. What format did you use to save? Can you post an image of your output settings?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by what format I used to save. When the render showed up in the UV image editor, went to image and clicked save image. I posted a picture of my settings for you.

Comment: there are many choices of formats to save your image, some do not support alpha channel (needed for transparency). Even in those formats that support alpha, there are settings in blender that allow you to use the alpha infomation or ignore it. Hence the request for clarification. Read through the link of the posted duplicate. If the solutions posted on it are not the answer to your question, then edit your question to add more information so that your question can be re-opened and the issue can be solved.

Comment: I found the answer, those ones don't explain it well, but in Internal you set it as a PNG image and then you uncheck the sky option.